# Basic Login function(Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html

I have been trying to make a login function as a way for me to learn Javascript. I cannot seem to get it to work fully though. I can get every alert except "you are logged in" to show.

I have edited it so now the function receives the userInput but it only works for "Harry" the other usernames do not work.

https://jsfiddle.net/b12o43ay/5/

```js
var users = ["Harry", "Julie", "Dewey", 5869];

function login() {

  var userInput = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
  if (userInput.length === 0) {
    alert('Please enter Username');
    return;
  } else {
    checkUserInput(userInput);
  }
};

function checkUserInput(userInput) {
  for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    console.log(users[i]);
    if (users[i] === userInput) {
      alert("You are logged in");
      return;
    } else {
      alert("Invalid username, please try again or if you are new register");
      return;
    }
  }
};
```

```html
<h1>Javascript Example</h1>

<input type="text" id="userInput" />
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="login()" />
```

Comment: You need to RECEIVE userInput in the second function since it is only known in the first: `function checkUserInput(userInput) {` - you pass it correctly

Comment: That's weird because it works now but I had tried that in there last night and it wasn't working. Although I was working on it pretty late. Thanks for your help :D.

Comment: It's still not working at the moment. So far only "Harry" logs in.

Comment: Because you alert and return immediately julie is not === harry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, You need to get `userInput` in `checkUserInput` function.
You're passing it `checkUserInput(userInput);` but not recieving.

So:

`function checkUserInput(userInput){…`

Also your alert and return immediately the user does not match the first in the array. Instead use indexOf, but note it is not compatible with IE<9

```
function checkUserInput(userInput){
  if(users.indexOf(userInput) > -1){
    alert("You are logged in");
    return;
  }
  else{
    alert("Invalid username, please try again or if you are new register");
    return;           
  }                
};
```

[indexOf](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof_array.asp) is much better way to check if element exists in array.

Comment: Yes, this works. Although it doesn't really help me to understand why my code is not functioning. Is there a way to get my code to check more than just "Harry"?

Comment: Because of return statement after first loop iteration.

Comment: Sorry I am being dumb here, but how do I fix it? I tried removing the return statement but it didn't help.

Comment: Original code works like this:

`for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {`

For every user:

check if `(users[i] === userInput)`
If yes: alert OK and RETURN
If no: alert NOK and RETURN

To fix this you should remove return from NOK condition otherwhise it stops on first check. That's why only Harry can log in.

Comment: This works. Thank you. How can I make this comment ^  as the accepted answer?

Answer (score 0):

You need to update add input parameter '**userInput**' to **checkUserInput** method. As you are passing *checkUserInput(**userInput**);* on line number 15 of your jsfiddle code.

```
        function checkUserInput(userInput){
            for(var i = 0; i < users.length; i++){
            console.log(users[i]);
              if (users[i] === userInput){
              alert("You are logged in");
              return;
              }
            else{
              alert("Invalid username, please try again or if you are new register");
              return;           
            }
          }};
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, never use client-side JavaScript to implement any kind of login functionality, as it is riddled with security issues. That said, there several things you can do to improve your code.

HTML:

```
<form>
  <input type="text" id="userInput" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Use a form for this and remove the inline event listener.

JS:

```
function login(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var input = userInput.value;
  if (input === '') {
    alert('Please enter Username');
    return;
  }

  checkUserInput(input);
}

function checkUserInput(name) {
  if (users.includes(name)){
    alert("You are logged in");
  } else {
    alert("Invalid username, please try again or if you are new register");
  }
}

var form = document.forms[0];
var userInput = document.getElementById("userInput");
var users = ["Harry", "Julie", "Dewey", "5869"];
form.addEventListener('submit', login);
```

Use [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to attach the listener. Move the call to `getElementById` out of the function to avoid repeatedly querying the DOM.

In the `login` function you can lose the `else` part of the `if` statement. In `checkUserInput` you can use the new [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) method to check if the name is included in the array, although browser support for this isn't very good (which is hopefully irrelevant if this is a learning exercise).

As you can see, I'm passing the value that the user entered into the text field to the call to `checkUserInput`. This was the main reason the code you posted wasn't working.

HTH.

Comment: User wanted to do this as an exercise.. Also I would return false from the   checkUserInput(input); so the result could be used in the login function. Lastly indexOf at least works in IE9+, includes does not work at all in IE

Comment: Yeah maybe. I didn't want to stray too far from the original code, as as you say, it's an exercise. But feel free to edit my answer if you think it'll add any value.

Comment: As for using indexOf, fair point, but it's much better to write using the latest syntax and transpile, no? Best of both worlds.

Comment: I strongly disagree unless you add polyfills or babel - I am not allowed to ignore the huge IE user base

Comment: Yeah Babel, basically. I'm not suggesting you ignore IE.

Comment: Hey thanks for the help but this answer seems a bit too complicated for me :D I am just trying to get my for loop to work.

Comment: I agree. Learn the basics first before learning React and using promises ;)